# A canonical natural transformation $H\to G$ when $G \dashv F \dashv H$ and $F$ is fully faithful.

Tags: category-theory, additive-categories

Let $F: \mathcal{A}\to \mathcal{B}$ and $G,H: \mathcal{B} \to \mathcal{A}$ be additive functors between additive categories so that we have adjunctions
$$
G \dashv F \dashv H
$$
and suppose that $F$ is fully faithful. Is it possible to construct a canonical morphism of functors $H \to G?$

Since $F$ is fully faithful, the natural morphisms 
$$
\operatorname{id}_{\mathcal{A}} \to H\circ F 
$$
and 
$$
G\circ F \to \operatorname{id}_{\mathcal{A}}
$$
are isomorphisms. Hence we get an isomorphism of functors 
$$
G\circ F \cong H \circ F
$$
From here it is easy to get the required morphism if $F$ is essentially surjective, but I cannot assume that, as the question becomes trivial.

My idea was to start with $\operatorname{Hom}(G(B), H(B))$ and then show that it is isomorphic a hom-set of the form $\operatorname{Hom}(X,X)$ for some $X$ and take the preimage of the identity... 
This does not seem to work out at all, for example 
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Hom}(H(B),G(B))&=\operatorname{Hom}(FH(B), FG(B))\\
&=\operatorname{Hom}(H(B), HFG(B))\\
&=\operatorname{Hom}(H(B), GFG(B)) \\
&=\operatorname{Hom}(GFH(B), G(B))
\end{align*}
and so on. There are also many isomorphisms of functors, like 
$$
FGF\cong F
$$
but using these also does not seem to help.

Comment: This is close to a recollement situation.

Comment: There's probably a Franjou paper somewhere summarizing all this.

Comment: @Randall I've skimmed through https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/documenta/vol-09/03.pdf but could not find anything relevant to this question

Comment: I see *a priori* two such natural transformations. The first one is
$$H\overset{\varepsilon_{GF}^{-1}H}\longrightarrow GFH\overset{G\varepsilon_{FH}}\longrightarrow G$$
The second one is 
$$H\overset{H\eta_{FG}}\longrightarrow HFG\overset{\eta_{HF}^{-1}G}\longrightarrow G$$ I am trying to show that these are equal.

Comment: What do you mean by "canonical"? Is the natural transformation that is 0 in every component canonical?

Comment: Ok they are really equals. The proof is not that difficult. You can prove that they are equals to a third natural transformations, which is the following : you can consider $$FH(A)\rightarrow A\rightarrow FG(A)$$. Since $F$ is fully faithful, this morphism is the image by $F$ of a  morphism $H(A)\rightarrow G(A)$. (You can prove directly that this is indeed a natural transformation, or prove that this morphism is the same as the previous two which are obviously natural transformations)